# Android Preset Reverb not being applied

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app that will take in audio and play back with reverb. This is the code I have. I have googled for hours and have not been able to solve the issue. The music is playing back but no reverb has been added. I am using an Acer Iconia A1 to test the app.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class Eq extends Activity {
String filePath;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/y.mp3";
    playSound();

}

public void playSound() {
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(filePath));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
    mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
    mReverb.setEnabled(true);

    player.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId());
    player.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

    // prepare for playback
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.start();

}
```

}

Comment: what does your logcat says?

Comment: What do you mean ? There are no errors in the logcat is that's what you mean. Sorry I am new to app development.